# Get url function returns duplicate urls multiple times

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

my geturl function returns the same url multiple times[Firebase console[console.log()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATVwd.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vKEK.jpg) and when I retrieve and display the url from firestore the image is duplicated and that messes up my UI.

I tried to use once: true, on the button that sends the url to the firebase database.
and also I tried stopPropagation(); with no success.

```
  constructor() {
    this.posts = [];
    this.files = [];

    this.post = {
      id: cuid(),
      username: "",
      caption: "",
      image: "",
    };

    this.$app = document.querySelector("#app");
    this.$firebaseAuthContainer = document.querySelector(
      "#firebaseui-auth-container"
    );
    this.$authUser = document.querySelector(".auth-user");
    this.$uploadBtn = document.querySelector(".upload-container");
    this.$postContainer = document.querySelector(".post-container");
    this.$filesToUpload = document.querySelector("#files");
    this.$sendBtn = document.querySelector("#send");
    this.$progress = document.querySelector("#progress");
    this.$uploadingBar = document.querySelector("#uploading");
    this.$captionText = document.querySelector("#caption-text");
    this.$posts = document.querySelector(".posts");
    this.$postTime = document.querySelector(".posted-time");

    this.ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(auth);
    this.handleAuth();

    this.addEventListener();

    this.displayPost();
  }

  handleAuth() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.username = user.displayName;
        this.userId = user.uid;
        this.redirectToApp();
      } else {
        this.redirectToAuth();
      }
    });
  }

  redirectToApp() {
    this.$firebaseAuthContainer.style.display = "none";
    this.$postContainer.style.display = "none";
    this.$app.style.display = "block";
    this.fetchPostsFromDB();
  }

  redirectToAuth() {
    this.$firebaseAuthContainer.style.display = "block";
    this.$app.style.display = "none";
    this.$postContainer.style.display = "none";
    this.ui.start("#firebaseui-auth-container", {
      signInOptions: [
        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      ],
      // Other config options...
    });
  }

  addEventListener() {
    document.body.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      this.handleClick(event);
      this.handleUploadClick(event);
      this.handlePostClick(event);
    });
    this.$filesToUpload.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
      this.handleFileChosen(event);
    });
    this.$captionText.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
      this.post.caption = event.target.value;
    });
    this.$authUser.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
      this.post.username = event.target.value;
    });
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.$authUser.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      this.handleLogout(event);
    });
  }

  handleLogout() {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signOut()
      .then(() => {
        this.redirectToAuth();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("ERROR OCCURED", error);
      });
  }
  handleUploadClick() {
    this.$uploadBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      this.redirectToPost();
    });
  }

  redirectToPost() {
    this.$postContainer.style.display = "block";
    this.$firebaseAuthContainer.style.display = "none";
    this.$app.style.display = "none";
  }

  handleFileChosen(event) {
    this.files = event.target.files;
    if (this.files.length > 0) {
      alert("File chosen!");
    } else {
      alert("No file chosen!");
    }
  }

  handlePostClick(e) {
    this.$sendBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      this.uploadToFB();
    });
  }

  uploadToFB() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
      const name = this.files[i].name;
      const upload = storage.ref(name).put(this.files[i]);
      upload
        .then((snapshot) => {
          console.log("'Successfully uploaded image");
          this.progressBar(snapshot);
          this.getFileUrl(name);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error, "Error Loading File Occured");
        });
    }
  }

  progressBar(snapshot) {
    const percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    this.$progress.value = percentage;
    if (percentage) {
      this.$uploadingBar.innerHTML = `${this.files[0].name} Uploaded`;
    }
  }
  getFileUrl(name) {
    const imageRef = storage.ref(name);
    imageRef
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then((url) => {
        (this.post.image = url), this.posts.push(this.post);
        console.log(this.post.image);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error, "Error Occured");
      });
  }

  fetchPostsFromDB() {
    var docRef = db.collection("users").doc(this.userId);
    docRef
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          console.log("Document data:", doc.data().posts);
          this.posts = doc.data().posts;

          this.displayPost();
        } else {
          // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
          console.log("No such document!");
          db.collection("users")
            .doc(this.userId)
            .set({
              posts: this.posts,
            })
            .then(() => {
              console.log("User successfully Created!");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
            });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
  }
  savePosts() {
    db.collection("users")
      .doc(this.userId)
      .set({
        posts: this.posts,
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Document successfully written!");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
      });
  }

  displayPost() {
    this.$posts.innerHTML = this.posts
      .map(
        (post) =>
          `<div class="post" id="${(post, this.userId)}">
          <div class="header">
            <div class="profile-area">
              <div class="post-pic">
                <img
                  alt="jayshetty's profile picture"
                  class="_6q-tv"
                  data-testid="user-avatar"
                  draggable="false"
                  src="assets/akhil.png"
                />
              </div>
              <span class="profile-name">${post.username}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="options" id="${(post, this.userId)}">
            <button type="button" class="more-btn"> 
            <div
            class="Igw0E rBNOH YBx95 _4EzTm"
            style="height: 24px; width: 24px"
            >
                <svg
                  aria-label="More options"
                  class="_8-yf5"
                  fill="#262626"
                  height="16"
                  viewBox="0 0 48 48" 
                  width="16"
                >
                  <circle
                    clip-rule="evenodd"
                    cx="8"
                    cy="24"
                    fill-rule="evenodd"
                    r="4.5"
                  ></circle>
                  <circle
                    clip-rule="evenodd"
                    cx="24"
                    cy="24"
                    fill-rule="evenodd"
                    r="4.5"
                  ></circle>
                  <circle
                    clip-rule="evenodd"
                    cx="40"
                    cy="24"
                    fill-rule="evenodd"
                    r="4.5"
                  ></circle>
                </svg>
                </div>
                </button>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="body">
            <img
              alt="Photo by Jay Shetty on September 12, 2020. Image may contain: 2 people."
              class="FFVAD"
              decoding="auto"
              sizes="614px"
              src="${post.image}"
              style="object-fit: cover"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="footer">
            <div class="user-actions">
              <div class="like-comment-share">
                <div>
                  <span class=""
                    ><svg
                      aria-label="Like"
                      class="_8-yf5"
                      fill="#262626"
                      height="24"
                      viewBox="0 0 48 48"
                      width="24"
                    >
                      <path
                        d="M34.6 6.1c5.7 0 10.4 5.2 10.4 11.5 0 6.8-5.9 11-11.5 16S25 41.3 24 41.9c-1.1-.7-4.7-4-9.5-8.3-5.7-5-11.5-9.2-11.5-16C3 11.3 7.7 6.1 13.4 6.1c4.2 0 6.5 2 8.1 4.3 1.9 2.6 2.2 3.9 2.5 3.9.3 0 .6-1.3 2.5-3.9 1.6-2.3 3.9-4.3 8.1-4.3m0-3c-4.5 0-7.9 1.8-10.6 5.6-2.7-3.7-6.1-5.5-10.6-5.5C6 3.1 0 9.6 0 17.6c0 7.3 5.4 12 10.6 16.5.6.5 1.3 1.1 1.9 1.7l2.3 2c4.4 3.9 6.6 5.9 7.6 6.5.5.3 1.1.5 1.6.5.6 0 1.1-.2 1.6-.5 1-.6 2.8-2.2 7.8-6.8l2-1.8c.7-.6 1.3-1.2 2-1.7C42.7 29.6 48 25 48 17.6c0-8-6-14.5-13.4-14.5z"
                      ></path>
                    </svg>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div class="margin-left-small">
                  <svg
                    aria-label="Comment"
                    class="_8-yf5"
                    fill="#262626"
                    height="24"
                    viewBox="0 0 48 48"
                    width="24"
                  >
                    <path
                      clip-rule="evenodd"
                      d="M47.5 46.1l-2.8-11c1.8-3.3 2.8-7.1 2.8-11.1C47.5 11 37 .5 24 .5S.5 11 .5 24 11 47.5 24 47.5c4 0 7.8-1 11.1-2.8l11 2.8c.8.2 1.6-.6 1.4-1.4zm-3-22.1c0 4-1 7-2.6 10-.2.4-.3.9-.2 1.4l2.1 8.4-8.3-2.1c-.5-.1-1-.1-1.4.2-1.8 1-5.2 2.6-10 2.6-11.4 0-20.6-9.2-20.6-20.5S12.7 3.5 24 3.5 44.5 12.7 44.5 24z"
                      fill-rule="evenodd"
                    ></path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="margin-left-small">
                  <svg
                    aria-label="Share Post"
                    class="_8-yf5"
                    fill="#262626"
                    height="24"
                    viewBox="0 0 48 48"
                    width="24"
                  >
                    <path
                      d="M47.8 3.8c-.3-.5-.8-.8-1.3-.8h-45C.9 3.1.3 3.5.1 4S0 5.2.4 5.7l15.9 15.6 5.5 22.6c.1.6.6 1 1.2 1.1h.2c.5 0 1-.3 1.3-.7l23.2-39c.4-.4.4-1 .1-1.5zM5.2 6.1h35.5L18 18.7 5.2 6.1zm18.7 33.6l-4.4-18.4L42.4 8.6 23.9 39.7z"
                    ></path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="bookmark">
                <div class="QBdPU rrUvL">
                  <svg
                    aria-label="Save"
                    class="_8-yf5"
                    fill="#262626"
                    height="24"
                    viewBox="0 0 48 48"
                    width="24"
                  >
                    <path
                      d="M43.5 48c-.4 0-.8-.2-1.1-.4L24 29 5.6 47.6c-.4.4-1.1.6-1.6.3-.6-.2-1-.8-1-1.4v-45C3 .7 3.7 0 4.5 0h39c.8 0 1.5.7 1.5 1.5v45c0 .6-.4 1.2-.9 1.4-.2.1-.4.1-.6.1zM24 26c.8 0 1.6.3 2.2.9l15.8 16V3H6v39.9l15.8-16c.6-.6 1.4-.9 2.2-.9z"
                    ></path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          
            <span class="caption">
              <span id="cap-username" class="caption-username"><b>${
                post.username
              }</b></span>
              <span class="caption-text" id="caption-text">
                ${post.caption}</span
              >
            </span>
            <span class="comment">
              <span class="caption-username"><b>akhilboddu</b></span>
              <span class="caption-text">Thank you</span>
            </span>
            <span class="comment">
              <span class="caption-username"><b>imharjot</b></span>
              <span class="caption-text"> Great stuff</span>
            </span>
            <span class="posted-time">${post.timestamp}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="add-comment">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Add a comment..." />
            <a class="post-btn">Post</a>
          </div>
        </div>
          
          
          `
      )
      .join("");
  }
}
const app = new App();
```

Comment: Hello! Please, add some code to your post. Your function and where do you call that functon from would be nice.

Comment: oops! sorry about that, the code is up now. it starts with ... uploadToFB() where the loop begins. thank you.

Comment: Still not a complete picture, but you seem to call this.savePosts() twice in a row — 1) from getFileUrl .then you first call savePosts(), then render() , and in render, you have another call of savePosts function. Is it OK?

Comment: Oh OK I see, that's not OK, I deleted savePosts() in render and now only have it in getUrl but the problem still persist. I just edited the code, I now posted the full JS code. hope it shows you the full picture.

Answer (score 0):

You are repeatedly attaching same event listeners.

Below is your code stripped down to demonstrate that after several clicks on body (anywhere) one click on $sendButton will trigger `console.log('SEND BUTTON CLICKED')` several times.

I believe that when you test your full code, you must make several clicks on auth, file selection — whatever — before you reach your button. All these clicks are handled by your document.body click listener, which attaches more listeners to sendButton.

See [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on MDN.

```js
class App {

    constructor() {

        this.$app = document.querySelector('#app');

        this.$sendBtn = document.querySelector('#send');

        this.addEventListener();

        console.log('constructor finished');
    }

    addEventListener() { // I'd rename this method to avoid confusion, BTW
        console.log('add ev listeners IN');
        
        document.body.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            console.log('DOC BODY click');
            this.handlePostClick(event);
        });
    }

    handlePostClick(e) {
        console.log('handlePostClick ATTACHER');
        this.$sendBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log('handlePostClick LISTENER');
            this.uploadToFB();
        });
    }

    uploadToFB() {
        console.log('—————→ SEND BUTTON CLICKED')
    }

}

const app = new App();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html style="height: 100%;">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>so 74615759</title>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<h5>click anywhere, see the console.</h5>

<div id="app">
    <button id="send">Send</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You have to fix it either by attaching handlers using `sendButton.onclick = handlerFunction` instead of addEventListener, or by marking sendButton with some class name after one addEventListener has been attached:

```
if (someButton.classList.contains('has-click-listener') === false) {
   someButton.addEventListener('click'), (event) => { 
     /* do stuff on click */ 
   });
   someButton.classList.add('has-click-listener');
}
```

Or use named functions instead of anonymous as event handlers as per addEventListener docs.

Comment: Thank you so much! I managed to solve the problem with your idea, the problem was with event Listeners, it was clicking on a button multiple times hence the duplicates... Now I have another issue with displayPosts(). Hope you could assist me again. I'm able to fetch posts from firebase storage and database then display them on my UI. however, I want each user to have his username associated with the posts he made. The problem im experiencing is whenever a new user logs in and post, his username overwrites the previous users. I wonder if I'm explaining clearly?

Comment: @Kamo sorry, mate, can't assist you more. I suggest you debug your app using good old console debugging — just trace what happens with params and class properties inside your functions with console.log() until you see a problem — and the browsers devtools network tab, or find someone else who has the time to help.